# SQL query to get customers who purchased product purchased by other customers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two entity order and line item
order captures information of order id, customer id and shipping details 
line item details will capture order id, product and quantity ordered.

I want to get customer_id who bought same product which he purchased is also purchased by three other customers.

```
select corder.customer_id,lineitem.prod_id
from lineitem
join corder on corder.order_id=lineitem.order_id
where prod_id in(select prod_id from lineitem
group by prod_id
having count(prod_id)>2)
```

This query gets customer id and prod, i further need to filter only customers who purchased prod by three other customers alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want products purchased by four or more customers.  That is:

```
select li.prod_id
from lineitem li join
     corder o
     on li.order_id = o.order_id
group by li.prod_id
having count(distinct o.customer_id) >= 4;
```

Now you want customers who purchased those products.  So:

```
select distinct c.customer_id
from corder co join
     lineitem li
     on li.order_id = o.order_id
where li.prod_id in (select li.prod_id
                     from lineitem li join
                          corder o
                          on li.order_id = o.order_id
                     group by li.prod_id
                     having count(distinct o.customer_id) >= 4
                    );
```